# Count, in how many sheets was the word used

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need function, that counts sheets, in which were used my word.
Example: have 100 sheets, and i need to findout, that word "CAR" is used in 76 of them.
Currently, im using formula below to findout all counts of that word.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&SHEETSNAME!$A$2:$A$102&"'!$A$1:$Z$10000");"*"&A1&"*"))
```

Is there something like that?

Comment: To me - your question ist not clear ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply amend your current formula to:

`=SUMPRODUCT(N(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&SHEETSNAME!$A$2:$A$102&"'!A1:Z10000");"*"&A1&"*")>0))`